# There is no ApplicationContext interface on spring framework (Eclipse IDE)

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I'm trying to start with Spring by creating a project and I'm trying to instantiate Spring's ApplicationContext interface and Eclipse does not recognize it, as if it did not exist.

Here my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>springapp-1</groupId>
  <artifactId>springapp-1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I think I have them all.

I am trying to create this(This is not my code, this is the code that I want to write):

[image]

And inside org.springframework.context only more packages appear, nothing more.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all @Hictus if you are working with Spring core (their is main method so I thought) then their is no need of spring-webmvc and spring-web dependency. You can remove them. Try after removing the mentioned dependency.

Comment: I'm starting with the most basic, but the idea is to use it to develope web application.

Comment: Spring core and Spring MVC are very much different lot of things will come if you want to upgrade to Spring MVC. So let us start with Spring core first Okay :)

Comment: Fisrt of all you remove the mentioned dependency. Check if their is any error in pom.xml or every maven Dependency is downloaded or not. May be your Maven Dependencies are not downloaded that's why its not able to find ApplicationContext.

Comment: @Aleksandr M I want to write the same code tht the image, but when I try to do import `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext` it's not available. Eclipse autocompletition only show me more packages.

Comment: @SachinSarawgi if I expand Maven dependencies, I can see they are all downloaded